# Complete Directed Graph Indegree and Outdegree summations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

Let the indegree of a vertex $v$ be $i(v)$ and the outdegree be $o(v)$. Consider a single tournament (a directed graph obtained by assigning a direction for each edge in an undirected complete graph) occurring. For $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $$s_a=\sum_v (i(v))^a$$ and $$t_a=\sum_v (o(v))^a.$$

For which $x$ does $s_x=t_x$ hold, regardless of the tournament?

Does $s_3\ge t_3$ imply $s_4\ge t_4$ ?

Does $s_4\ge t_4$ imply $s_5\ge t_5$ ?

**Progress**: So clearly $s_1 = t_1$ because of # of edges being the same, but I also noticed $s_2 = t_2$ for the cases I drew out and I'm not sure how to prove this yet.

Comment: There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217442/graph-theory-problem-about-outdegree-and-indegree/217451#217451) (minus a few details) that $s_2=t_2$.

Comment: As mentioned by sfs2007, this question is problem M3 [here](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2021/entpro21.pdf), violating Math StackExchange's ["Contest problem" policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy), so I am flagging this question for the moderators to be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not answer this question. This problem is pretty much copy-pasted from this year's MIT PRIMES Entrance Test: https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2021/entpro21.pdf

Check Problem M3. It is literally the same.

In the MIT PRIMES rules, it explicitly says "Note that posting these problems on problem-solving websites before the application deadline is strictly forbidden! Applicants who do so will be disqualified, and their parents and recommenders will be notified."

Solutions are due on December 1 - this is a clear violation of the rules.