# Working with the Indegrees and Outdegrees of a Tournament

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

When going through an Indian math magazine, I found this cool problem, but I don't really get how to solve it:

Given a tournament $T$ on $m$ vertices with the vertex set $V(T)$, show that $n=2$ is the only solution where $n>1$ to the following equation: $$\sum_{v\in V(T)} \bigl((\operatorname{indeg} v)^n - (\operatorname{outdeg}v)^n\bigr) = 0.$$

I know how to show that $n=2$ works. For all $n \ge 3$, I tried using an induction argument but it didn't really lead me anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas for how to prove this?

Comment: Aren't $n=0$ and $n=1$ solutions?  What am I missing?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add it into the problem. It also said that $n>1$

Comment: I proved the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868982/complete-directed-graph-indegree-and-outdegree-summations/3871456#3871456).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is sloppily worded.

In a tournament on $2k+1$ vertices where each vertex has in-degree $k$ and out-degree $k$, the formula holds for any value of $n$, so the problem must mean that there is no value of $n>2$ such that the formula holds for every tournament.  This is not what it seems to say.  I read it as asserting that there is no value of $n>2$ such that the formula holds for *any* tournament, but we've just seen that this is false.

To prove what I think is the intended statement, it's enough to consider a tournament on $4$ vertices, one of which has out-degree $3$, and the others all with out-degree $1$.  If the formula holds, then $$3^n+3\cdot1= 3\cdot2^n+1\cdot0^n$$or
$$3^{n-1}+1=2^n$$ and it's easy to show that this is false for $n>2$.